# display row column numbers in myeclipse statusbar

Tags: html, jsf-2, ide, statusbar, myeclipse

Is there any option available in myeclipse for showing column numbers of xhtml page.

If the cursor is place in java file automatically row number and column number is displayed
but not in xhtml pages.

Comment: The line and column number of the current cursor position is shown on the status bar. This is standard eclipse behavior for editors. It works with MyEclipse 2014, what release are you using?

Comment: @TonyWeddle MyEclipse 10.7.1, It didn't show column numbers at status bar, but in java files row and column numbers are displayed at status bar.

Comment: I've tried 10.7.1 and I see the line and column in the status bar. Could you ensure that you are opening the html file with the MyEclipse HTML Editor, the MyEclipse Visual HTML Designer or the Web Page Editor, as I've tried all of those and see the line and column. There is no setting to add or remove the line and column from the status bar. However, if you open in the visual designer, you won't see any line and column if you stay in the visual design pane, rather than typing in the text pane.

Comment: @TonyWeddle it works. Previously an error is occurred in xhtml page at column 7. At that time I didn't open in MyEclipse Visual HTML Designer, I opened it in default MyEclipse Visual JSF Designer. Row and Column numbers are shown in Status bar. Post your comment as answer. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried 10.7.1 and I see the line and column in the status bar. Could you ensure that you are opening the html file with the MyEclipse HTML Editor, the MyEclipse Visual HTML Designer or the Web Page Editor, as I've tried all of those and see the line and column. There is no setting to add or remove the line and column from the status bar. However, if you open in the visual designer, you won't see any line and column if you stay in the visual design pane, rather than typing in the text pane.