# Lost column/line fields in the status bar using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I used to see the line and column (character count) in the status bar of Eclipse (actually Precision32's version of Eclipse), but somehow it went away. According to the Eclipse UI guidelines it's supposed to be there:

> Editors with source lines of text should show the current line and
>   optionally column numbers the status line. It's optional for the
>   editor to show line numbers for each line in the editor itself.

But I can't find anything that tells how to turn it on. I didn't update my editor, AFAIK.

Edit:
The editor is active. 
I have no idea what happened, but it started working again.  Might be when I installed Juno eclipse, maybe some register settings in common were touched? I hate doing a re-install to fix a problem as you lose settings and it isn't getting to the root cause, but for this round I'll have to accept it.

Comment: This question is similar, but didn't give me an answer.  In fact, there may not be a setting in Eclipse itself? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556089/display-row-column-numbers-in-myeclipse-statusbar

Comment: In Eclipse Luna, go to Window>Preferences>General>Editors>Text Editors and there is a check box for Show Line Numbers. Not sure about the status bar but mine does show line:column.

Comment: That shows line numbers in the text editor pane.  I'm looking for column number, which is supposed to be shown down in the status bar.  The best I can do is turn on the print margin (in the same preferences page), and set it to a specific column, but that's an ugly work-around.

Comment: Remember that line number and column number will be shown only for the text editors when they made active. Check whether editor is active of not. Also share the screenshot.